# Super-user privileges for Chromium browser

Tags: linux, chrome, ps, software-updates, privileges

After `apt-get install chromium` and running it on Debian 12,
`ps alx | grep -e ^F -e ^5.*chromium` returns:

```
F   UID     PID    PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
5  1000 3452315 3452313  20   0 33884428 16712 do_sys S  ?          0:00 /usr/lib/chromium/chromium --type=zygote --crashpad-handler-pid=3452306 --enable-crash-reporter=,built on Debian 12.4, running on Debian 12.4 --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable
```

This executed on LUbuntu 18 after `apt-get install chromium-browser` (which does
`snap install chromium` in its `/var/lib/dpkg/info/chromium-browser.preinst`):

```
F   UID     PID    PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
5  1000  197953  197951  20   0 33909972 1228 do_sys S   ?          0:00 /snap/chromium/2729/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome --type=zygote --crashpad-handler-pid=197944 --enable-crash-reporter=,snap --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable
```

where the flag `F` value `5` means *used super-user privileges* according to `man ps`.

**Why does the Chromium browser need and get super-user privileges when installed by the regular package management and run by a non-privileged user ?**

ChatGPT says this would be for installation or updating, but I don't believe that because I did installation using regular `apt-get` and updates would be done by `unattended-upgrades` on Debian or `snapd` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BTW :

> where the flag F value 5 means used super-user privileges according to
> man ps.

Indeed but not only : 5 = 1 + 4

> PROCESS FLAGS
> The sum of these values is displayed in the "F" column, which is provided by the flags output specifier:
>
> ```
>            1    forked but didn't exec
>            4    used super-user privileges
> ```

The *forked but didn't exec* flag confirming that the `--type=zygote`  parameter set in the chrome process you list has actually been taken into account, successfully making it a [zygote process](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/linux/zygote.md#appendix-b-memory-impact-of-relocations).

In addition, please note the use of the past tense "*used*" meaning that the report does not reflect current status regarding capabilities that might well have been dropped right after process initialization. (It is considered as best practice for a process to drop privileges as soon as they are no longer needed)

---

For obvious security reasons, [Chromium will resort to sandboxing](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/design/sandbox.md).
Except in the case of now very old kernels, it will be using the [User namespaces sandboxing technique](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/linux/sandboxing.md#User-namespaces-sandbox). A zygote process is responsible for setting it up.

> Security-wise, the Zygote is responsible for setting up and
> bookkeeping the namespace sandbox.

Even though this technique is based on unprivileged namespaces, the process responsible for setting it up actually needs the priviledged [`CAP_SYS_CHROOT`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) capability [but only **until the sandbox is fully engaged.**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=312380)

So, in short : That process actually needs super-user capabilities in order to… enable everything running unpriviledged… ;-) and will just drop them as soon as the appropriate environment is set.

Comment: I did not say flag value 5 means nothing else than "used super-user privileges" so I still _think_ my wording was correct, but I'm not sure because I'm not a native speaker of English. Do you think it is incorrect to say A means B if A actually means B and C ? How to say that in correct English if one doesn't want to mention C because that is irrelevant ?

Comment: @Juergen : Ho well… not being a native speaker myself… I don't qualify for arguing about that. My intention was only to underline the fact that the *forked but didn't exec* flag is also set. (since it has its importance in this particular question). But anyway, I'm happy to remove my indeed questionable "*This is not completely exact*" statement.

Comment: Seems I missd an important part: How is the fact that the process forked but did not exec important for this particular question ?

Comment: @Juergen : I updated my answer with regards to the importance of the *process forked but did not exec* flag. In short : Chromium-browser spawns just many processes. This flag confirms the process you listed IS the one setting up the sandbox, incidentally justifying the explanation I provide (need for CAP_SYS_CHROOT)